# How can I call a function import from Node.js package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the `sendSafely` API to pull data, I'm having a hard trying to call this particular function.

```
var sendSafely = new SendSafely("https://host.sendsafely.com/", "apikey", "apisecret");

sendSafely.verifyCredentials(function(email)  {
    console.log("Connected to SendSafely as user "  +  email);
});
```

How do I call this function (verifyCredentials)?

Comment: What errors do you get from the above snippet of code?

Comment: (1) Have you installed the package? (npm install @sendsafely/sendsafely) (2) Do you require the package? (const SendSafely = require('@sendsafely/sendsafely');

Comment: Not clear whether the method call results in an error or not. The snippet looks okay in terms of syntax. Please share logs and other data for debugging.

Comment: Hello, do u have any error log? I suggest you need to follow all the steps on the following link: https://sendsafely.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042056772

Comment: When I run this code it runs  but doesnt output anything. Its supposed to verify the api key and api secret and spit out which email is associated to those api key and secret, Example ``` Connected to SendSafely as user myemail.@gmail.com ```

Comment: @SumnerEvans @ofirBaruch @AbrarHossain  there are no errors so I believe the syntax is right. I just need to call ```verifyCredentials``` so it can spit out an output. I just don't know how to call it.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [QuickStart example](https://github.com/SendSafely/JavaScript-Node-Client-API/blob/master/examples/CreateNewPackage/CreateNewPackage.js) within the Github repository for their Node library, there is some error event handling logic which should give you the details of the error.

Try this instead:

```
const SendSafely = require('@sendsafely/sendsafely');
  
var sendSafely = new SendSafely("https://www.sendsafely.com/", "apikey", "apisecret");

sendSafely.on('sendsafely.error', function(error, errorMsg) {
    console.log(error + ": " + errorMsg);
});

sendSafely.verifyCredentials(function(email)  {
    console.log("Connected to SendSafely as user "  +  email);
});
```